# How to pass disabled attribute to some elements in react classes?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I wanted to make universal input-class using reactjs-bootstrap and to use it in my form. Code of my class:

```
const TextField = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        var label = (this.props.label != null) ? this.props.label : "";
        var name = (this.props.name != null) ? this.props.name : "";
        var value = (this.props.value != null) ? this.props.value : "";
        return (
            <FormGroup>
                <ControlLabel>{label}</ControlLabel>
                <FormControl type="text" placeholder={label} name={name}
                             value={value} onChange={this.props.onChange}
                />
                <FormControl.Feedback />
            </FormGroup>
        );
    }
});
```

In my form-class  I use it so:

```
 <div className="col-md-3">
     <TextField label="Label"
         name='label_id'
         value={data.label_id} />
 </div>
```

In my form i have some inputs, which must be dissabled. In documentation i saw that exists attribute `dissabled`, but when I write:

```
<div className="col-md-3">
    <TextField label="Label"
        name='label_id'
        value={data.label_id}
        dissabled />
</div>
```

it doesn't works. I think this is because of universal `TextField`-class. How can I fix this problem in my case?If I specify dissabled-atribute in parent-class, all inputs become dissabled..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a `disabled` prop to your `TextField`, which you did already, and consume it by `FormControl` which supports `disabled` prop according its usage.

```
<FormControl
  type="text"
  placeholder={label}
  name={name}
  value={value}
  disabled={this.props.disabled}   <-- this disables the text input.
  onChange={this.props.onChange}
/>
```